# JS performace: why don't load uninitialized or deleted elements

Tags: javascript, v8

The [Performance Tips for JavaScript in V8](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/) says:

> Don't load uninitialized or deleted elements. And gives the following examples.

```
// example1
a = new Array();
for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
  a[0] |= b;  // Oh no!
}

// example2
a = new Array();
a[0] = 0;
for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
  a[0] |= b;  // Much better! 2x faster.
}
```

Now I am wondering why just the first element of the array uninitialized can cause the huge performance difference. I think after the `a[0]` is assigned for the first time in the loop, the two examples should perform the same. So it should takes almost the same time as they run.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: This gets weirder and weirder.  See this jsperf which makes zero logical sense in Chrome: http://jsperf.com/empty-array-vs-initialized-array.  It works as expected in Firefox and IE11 (both cases same speed).

Comment: @jfriend00 The first one can be immediately supported by an integer array while the second one can't. Not pretending I'm sure this is what really happens with the current version of V8 but this reasoning often leads to better performances.

Comment: @dystroy - are you commenting on the two cases in my jsperf or on the OP's code?  My two cases both have an array initialized with one or more integers.

Comment: @jfriend00 In the test case I see we have `[0]` (an integer array) then `[]` (an untyped array).

Comment: @dystroy - And, the first one in my jsFiddle `[0]` (the one you're calling an integer array) is substantially SLOWER in Chrome.  That's what is weird.  Are integer arrays a lot slower than Chrome's internal untyped arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The first array starts as a dictionary or an untyped object array (which can hold `undefined`) and will likely keep being a dictionary for a time before being converted to an array, which is costly.

The second array *can* from the start be supported by an integer array which is a very fast structure.

Note that those optimizations are subject to change so it's possible the way the engine acts is not the same when you read this answer...

Comment: `a` is declared as an empty Array in both code examples.  It doesn't have to be converted into an array in either code example.

Comment: @jfriend00 Internally V8 uses different types of array. For example a dictionary when you can pass any value as key or value. And a compact int array when you'll only pass small contiguous integers as keys and only 32 bit integers as values (which is probably the fastest internal storage type for an array).

Comment: All arrays support JS object functionality (not sure why you're calling it a dictionary as that isn't a JS type).  You can add an arbitrary property to any array.

Comment: @jfriend00 We're speaking of the storage implementation chosen by V8. V8 defines more internal types than there are specified types. I edited my answer for better clarity.

Comment: I don't see that any edit to your answer was actually applied to clarify this.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I've removed the article I linked to, because it wasn't very clear on arrays (it's more about objects).

Comment: @dystroy However, if I change `a[0] |= b;` to `a[b] = b`, the two examples run almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that in the second example, the 0 index value of `a` is not `undefined` - and since you've assigned a value to that index, now when it is evaluated it is evaluating against an established/realized index+value.

this may or may not be exactly right, but that's the gist.  you can also always create an entry on jsperf.com and test out this theory